# How do I store JSON response to Array - Python request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I can't find a solution because the lack of understanding of programming.
I have created multiple Python Scripts where I do API calls to get results, the results are converted to JSON.

I want to store two specific fields from the JSON result for each user in an array, so I then later can make a "search" based of a users input(field), match it to the array and send a post request later.

The fields I want is: 'email' and 'userid', so when I search for the input (email) I can retrieve the userid, and send the post call from a button click.

So I understand that I can retrieve either email or userid by using the teo first lines to print the values. But the issue is when i try to store it in the array:

```
users = response.json()

print(users['user'][1]['userid']) #get user id
print(users['user'][1]['email']) #get email

json_length = len(users['user']) #get amount of users

print(json_length)

user_list = []
for i in users:
    user_details = {"id":None, "email":None}
    user_details['id'] = users['userid'][i]
    user_details['email'] = users['email'][i]
    user_list.append(user_details)

print(user_list)
```

I get the following error:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError list indices must be integers or
> slices, not str
> File  "C:...test2.py",
> line 32, in 
> user_details['id'] = users['user'][i]['userid']

The JSON (multiple fields are removed and renamed)

```
{
   "total":"2001",
   "totalcount":"2",
   "user":[
      {
         "userid":1,
         "name":{
            "firstname":"John",
            "lastname":"Doe (Inactive)"
         },
         "email":"j.doe@something.com",
         "status":"Inactive",
         "organisation":{
            "orgname":"something",
            "orgid":1
         },

      },
      {
         "userid":2,
         "name":{
            "firstname":"Emma",
            "lastname":"Hart (Inactive)"
         },
         "email":"e.hart@otherthing.com",
         "status":"Inactive",
         "organisation":{
            "orgname":"otherthing",
            "orgid":2
         },
      }
   ]
}
```

Any help for pointing what I'm doing wrong or help?

Comment: Your error doesn't match the code you posted

Comment: My mistake! I tried adding the ['userid'] after the [i], but forgot to remove that when I ran the code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping over the full JSON response keys, not the actual users list, then `i` would be each user object, so use that rather than the response again

Try

```
for i in users.get('user', []):
    ... 
    user_details['id'] = i['userid']
    user_details['email'] = i['email']
```

You can also build that list in one line

```
user_list = [ {"id":u["userid"], "email":u["email"]} for u in users.get('user', []) ]
print(user_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Finally able to store them - this will make the rest hopefully easier for a newbie like me!